# Which font is used for this Cyrillic text?

Tags: font-identification, serif

I was given the task to engrave an inscription in this font:

[image: The needed font]
<sup>Click image for full size</sup>

But I have no clue what is written in it nor what font it is written in... Can anyone help me discover what font was used here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font in question is [a_AlgeriusRough](http://www.fonts-online.ru/font/a_AlgeriusRough)

[image]

THE CREDIT TO THE IDENTIFICATION IS OF JOHNB!

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you translate the text, but the font used is some flavor of [Algerian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algerian_(virtual_typeface)) (I'll recognize that "A" anywhere!). [**Algerian Basic D**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/algerian/basic-d/) looks similar to what's used in your image, but I suspect it is customized. The "K" is noticably different, but uses the same style as the "R".

[image: Algerian Basic D sample]

I am not sure if there exists an Algerian font that contains Cyrillic characters, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've found the font with your help, thus I upvoted your answer....